# 2D draw mode can't get non-transparent line and paint color

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm quite new and the vocabularies are difficult for me who is not a professional drawer and so I'm having a lot of trouble looking for the help I need.

Basically, I'm unable to draw a line without transparency. I don't remember clicking on anything unusual in 2D animation (draw mode)

Even when I try to paint (fill), it is transparent and so I have to go over several times to make it thick enough so we don't see through. Is there a button or something to get rid of transparency? My strength is at max.

Please help me. I spent so much time trying to find solution but I couldn't find.

[image]

I think opacity is on max.

This is the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally discovered how to solve this problem! For anyone who encounters the same issue, here is the solution!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is your opacity on max? Check the **Object Data Properties** Tab (the one with the green squiggly line). If that's not it, can you post a pic with that Tab open?

Hmm, check all the layers for their opacity, other than that maybe the Masking causes it? (the dot next to the layer name)